# PHPExcel - Erasing formula's not supported by PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have an excel template saved in the server. When I write some data using PHPExcel library to the existing template and save it, it writes the data but erases all the formulas from the excel file such as linest, etc. while being saved. So when I open the excel file, it shows the data written to it but the file does not contain any formulas. Is it something that I am doing wrong or PHPExcel does not support those functions? I tried looking at other questions on stackoverflow but could not find anything similiar to mine.
Below is my code for writing to the excel file.

```
<?php 
/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$sheetname = "Input";

$inputFileName = "templates/test_template2.xlsx";
$inputFileType = "Excel2007";
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
    //  Read rows 1 to 200 and columns A to PP only for avoiding memory limit errors 
        if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 200) {
           if (in_array($column,range('A','PP'))) { 
           return true;
           }
       } 
       return false;
   }
}

$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter();

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(true);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//random data for testing
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B15', '234');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C15', '2554');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D15', '436');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B16', '246546');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C16', '576');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D16', '457'); 
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true); 
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(true);
$objWriter->save('test_template_edit.xlsx');
echo "Data written and saved to the excel file";
?>
```

EDIT :
    So after changing the memory and time limit and uploading a file with fewer columns, I was able to keep the formatting and formulas. However, when viewing the workbook later, all of the charts on adjacent worksheets are disappearing even when I am using setIncludeCharts(TRUE) both before the file is uploaded and output. Any suggestions?

Comment: PHPExcel supports almost all formulae and functions of MS Excel, and certainly shouldn't remove content (such as formulae) from cells when reading or writing, so I simply cannot understand or explain how it can fail to write the formulae that have been read from your template.

Comment: But knowing exactly what is in your template file might help to diagnose the problem

Comment: `range('A','PP')` will only be `array('A', 'B', 'C', ... , 'P')`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php. So only columns `A` to `P` will be read.

Comment: My template is an xlsx workbook that has around 50 columns for raw data with around 2000 records. Then I have formula to the right of these columns that calculate things from the raw values such as LINEST (Linear Least Squares). Even when writing 4 or 5 individual cells in the raw data removes the formulae and format in the remaining cells .

Comment: So after changing the memory and time limit and uploading a file with fewer columns, I was able to keep the formatting and formulas. However, when viewing the workbook later, all of the charts on adjacent worksheets are disappearing even when I am using setIncludeCharts(TRUE) both before the file is uploaded and output. Any suggestions?